# Delete captured images with HTML5

Tags: android, html

I am currently developing a website for mobile devices. The website needs to analyze pictures taken from the camera of the phone. I currently grab the image data via:

`<input type="file" id="input_photo" accept="image/*;capture=camera" capture="camera"/>`

However on all Android devices I tested (Android is the main plattform for now) and for all browsers (Stock Browser, Chrome, Firefox) the image is either saved to /sdcard/DCIM/browser_photos/ or simply /sdcard/. 
I don't need those pictures so my question is, if there is a way to either let the browser know to not save those pictures permanently or to delete those pictures after analyzing them.

PhoneGap or similar APIs are not an option. I want to stick to pure HTML5 and JavaScript.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just cannot access device's storage to remove something from the browser - it will be a security issue. The same thing is with regular OS browsers - the only thing you can do is use a file input to browse for file to upload - nothing more.

Comment: That is what I feared. So I am either going to stick with this issue or create a workaround. I will try to delete these pictures with a native App started via Intent. I hope this will work eventually

Comment: That's the only way you can do it.